# How number of items in IN clause relates to index usage

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, amazon-rds

I'm trying to optimize a query but I'm seeing a weird behavior I don't understand.

I have a table contains almost 2 million records, with an index on column "status_code" which is tinyint.

When I call the query with 10 numbers in In clause, mysql do a full table scan

```
select * from `table` as t
where t.code in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

[image: full scan]

When I call it with 9 numbers in the IN clause, the index is used.

```
select * from `table` as t
where t.code in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

[image: index]
Note: Number of rows here is '9' although the query returns only 1 row.

I'm using Amazon RDS, I need to understand why is this behavior, and if there is any kind of configuration that controls this.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each query.  And SHOW INDEXES FROM `table`;

Comment: You mentioned it's a `TINYINT`, but how many actual distinct values appear in this column in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `IN()` predicate, MySQL would have to analyze the index for each value in your list, estimating the benefit of using the index. When you use long lists of values, calculating the optimizer's estimate becomes expensive, even before executing the query.

In MySQL 5.6, they established a threshold so a list of 10 or more items in an `IN()` predicate skipped the index-dive-per-value work, and just guessed at the value of using the index based on previously collected stats about the index. This is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/range-optimization.html in the subsection "Equality Range Optimization of Many-Valued Comparisons."

You can tune the threshold with the variable `eq_range_index_dive_limit`. In MySQL 5.6, the default is 10. In MySQL 5.7, they realized that the default of 10 was too small, so they increased the default value to 200. You could change this variable to 200 to be like the MySQL 5.7 behavior.

I notice you are using RDS. The default on RDS is sometimes different from the default in stock MySQL, so the default might be 10 even if you're using RDS based on MySQL 5.7. Review your db parameter group.

Comment: That was the problem, really thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Using index is driven by stats. I don't have precise info for MySQL, but PostgreSQL will go seq-scan if calculated result will be bigger then 2% of the table. In your case it can be other value, but mechanism is the same.

DB uses stats to see if your query returns more then small percentage of the table - in that case - sequence read is used. MS SQL Server will not use index if table is smaller then 5MB - that is faster. By that I mean - it is typical, and all RDBMS goes that way. Sometimes that fails - as you can see.

What to do with it? You can `analyze table` to update stats. You can use hint `use_stat_tables` to turn off stored stats... In PostgreSQL you could change histograms for the table to have more precise results, but I don't know anything like that for MySQL. Also there are many drivers, and this particular problem can be solved at this level.

Providing `explain`s would not change much here. MySQL has poor explain, also nature of the problem is quite obvious.

As a side note. That is not related to RDS - that is typical problem for RDBMS. Different systems deals with it in different way, and MySQL is not a leader here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the problem was actually the eq_range_index_dive_limit config :).